# calling Activity from anothe package giving error

Tags: android

```
Intent ints = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LocationShare.class);               startActivity(ints);
return true;
```

Following are the errors

```
10-18 18:36:07.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
10-18 18:36:07.953: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at com.mycabfare.Mainoptionpage.onOptionsItemSelected(Mainoptionpage.java:58)
```

Comment: Please add the whole error stack..

Comment: look at code line number 58 in  Mainoptionpage.java class file in onOptionsItemSelected() method, what is gping wrong, debugg it. and put whole error log here.

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark since you don't have the whole error stack, but instead of starting the Activity using the Application Context, pass in the Activity that is calling it. Activity extends Context and will work as a valid argument. In essence, instead of `getApplicationContext()` use `new Intent(this, LocationShare.class);`.

Comment: hey thanks every one. actly the problem is in my manifest file.

Comment: so while registering activity i have given package name.

Comment: i.e   android:name = "com.mycabface.sharelocation.LocationShare"